# Huge "system data" file on SD card

Tags: sd-card, internal-storage

I am running out of space in my SD card on Android ICS and I noticed that a huge file "System data" is taking up to 500MB. Is this normal? How can I reduce its size?

Comment: Could you quote the exact error message? And no, I wouldn't consider it normal, be it just for the question "What do system data have do do on the SD card?" In case "System data" doesn't stand for a file name: Did you possibly install some "big app" on your SD card? (Could be meaning App2SD-related stuff then)

Comment: Furthermore, what is the precise file path to that file? 

Odds are, you can just delete it, since no *real* system data is actually saved in /sdcard/  -- 
Its probably just a poor translation....

Comment: is the folder "/sdcard/android/"? That is the folder that is the recommended path for applications to store additional data to the sdcard.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen such a file on ICS.

You could simply try to move the file to your PC and see if everything works. I think it's pretty safe to do so, because critical system files are usually not placed on the SD card.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but here is *new* solution:
Just dial *#9900# on the phone and then select from `delete dumpstate/logcat`.

This method worked for me. This started to happen on my new 128gb sd card.
It is a cheap Chinese one, so that might be a reason.
But every time I delete bigger files, I have to wait a bit, issue this command, and that gives me back my space. Retro feel, but it works, and it was 1/4th the price of a Kingston card, so could not care less.

Taken from here: http://androidforums.com/threads/low-on-space-system-data-huge.278837/

**Thanks for downvoting a method that actually works. Just StackExchange things, I guess.**

Comment: Note that this MMI code [doesn't](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/157647/clear-massive-system-data-file-on-lg-g3) [work](https://androidforums.com/threads/low-on-space-system-data-huge.278837/page-2) on some phones like the LG G3 and G4. Not sure how to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's normal> I had a similar issue on my Samsung S2.
Some people have reported that this was created by the [generation of log files (alog_*)](http://androidforums.com/t-mobile-mytouch-4g/278837-low-space-system-data-huge.html) ; [others from `anr_history.txt`](http://www.whataandroid.com/showthread.php/29459-Low-on-Space-System-data-huge!-Android-and-T-Mobile-MyTouch-4G/page3).

If you can root your device, you can safely delete these files.
If you cannot root your device, then you need to factory restet the phone in order to wipe all the data.

Answer (score 0):

It could be ".android_secure"folder. Is it where apps were "moved to SD card"?  It's Wierd because some apps don't find this folder, I only figures it out using root apps.

Comment: That's the reason behind it: Without root, you cannot access `/data/data/*` either, where the app originally resides. So Android is keeping you from it as well when you've moved it to SD card. You only can browse its contents with root powers – or with a card reader attached to your computer :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like this problem.
https://androidforums.com/threads/low-on-space-system-data-huge.278837/

The *#9900# solution works for many people, but not all.

If you can root I think you can delete the log files. Otherwise, you could try a factory reset.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).