# Show size of biggest folders and files in system data

Tags: internal-storage, storage

### 1. Summary

I don't find, how I can view, which folders and files are the biggest in my system data. So I can manually decide which files to delete and which not.

---

### 2. Expected behavior

Ideally to have behavior as in [**SpaceSniffer**](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/index.html) Windows program.

[image: SpaceSniffer]

SpaceSniffer can show sizes of system Windows files.

I can't get similar behavior for Android.

---

### 3. Data

- ASK Benefit S401
- Android 5.1.1
- CyanogenMod 12.1 ROM
- Rooted

When I install CyanogenMod, system data size — ~700 MB; at the time — ~1,5 GB.

Several hundred megabytes — apps data, for which I would consider the possibility of removal.

---

### 4. Not helped

#### 4.1. SpaceSniffer Android alterntaives

All doesn't show system data files and folders.

- [**DiskUsage**](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.google.android.diskusage/)

  [image: DiskUsage]
- [**DataSize Explorer**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nexradsoftware.datasizeexplorer&hl=en)

  [image: DataSize Explorer]
- [**Grid Size File Manager**](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1034019)

  [image: Grid Size File Manager]

I don't find another [**DiskUsage alternatives**](https://alternativeto.net/software/diskusage/?platform=android), that can help me.

---

### 5. Do not offer

1. Yes, I understand that operations with system Android files may be risky. I understand that I do actions at my own risk.
2. Yes, I know about [**SD card partitioning**](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/6435/202755), and I move all my apps to SD card use [**Apps2SD**](https://www.apps2sd.info/).
3. Yes, I can view system data files, use any file manager, that support root — I use [**Amaze**](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.amaze.filemanager/), — but I don't find file manager, that:

   - correct sort folders and files in system data
   - show files/folders size of all files in screen.

---

### 6. Related questions

My question is not duplicate for these questions; please look carefully.

- [**How to see what is stored in System memory area?**](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/55761/202755)
- [**Huge «system data» file on SD Card**](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/26906/202755)
- [**How do I get rid of “System Data” that takes up half my hard drive?**](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/140038/202755)

Comment: SDMaid is also a good app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Solid Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer2&hl=en_AU) and grant it root access. This is the most feature filled file manager that I've tried. Visit the Root (/) partition, click three dots on top right and properties. There you can see a breakdown of the content, file types and top 20 files (it does take a while to index this).

[image: Solid Explorer example]

Alternatively with a terminal emulator use the common Linux tool `du` and sort by size:

`du -ah(x) | sort -n -r | head -n (number_to_show)`

I tried to find a build of `ncdu` for Android which would be ideal but no luck. If you have Ubuntu/Arch/some other system with a package manager installed you could simply apt-get it.

Comment: One problem: Solid Explorer is a great tool, but not FOSS :( . Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных true that's why I was a bit hesitant providing it GDrive access. SFTP to my VPS works really well though.

Comment: If you haven't tried termux you might want to check it out. It gives you a terminal with apt and doesn't require root.  It has a package for ncdu.  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux

Answer (score 0):

I have tried five or six apk installed file management space app that can obtain root permissions. In addition to https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.google.android.diskusage/, other apps are **very, very slow to index**, may be associated with magisk or partitions? So I chose to su root permissions using adb shell.

Both ncdu and gdu (more feature-rich than ncdu) have compiled arm static binaries. Can be used directly in adb shell. The specific method of use can refer to https://android.stackexchange.com/a/256220/397711