# Lenovo S5 storage filled with invisible files

Tags: storage, lenovo, data

I have a Lenovo S5 with 64gb internal storage. I had this problem for a while now, so i really need some help.

Any file manager that I can find sums up all my files and aplications at under 20 gb, however i only have 3 gb free.

About 40 gb are filled with invisible/unfindable files. I looked online for answers many time, and I tried using "Android terminal emulator" with the command "df -h" and got this result, can anyone make something of it?[image]

Comment: Starting point: our [storage tag wiki](/tags/storage/info) has some pointers on how to find out what "ate" your storage.

Comment: There is one simple answer: You as the use and your apps don't have access to those files. Therefore those files are "invisible" to you. That is the Android storage design.

Comment: So how do I delete those files (or are they actually part of apps, but not registered so?)

Comment: basically yes, not all apps will delete it's files on uninstall. factory reset will solve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What Is Using Up My Storage/Data on Android Phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215678/what-is-using-up-my-storage-data-on-android-phone)